# Array null given in footer

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Page says: Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in xxxx/footer.php on line 44

```
<?php $i++;?>
<?php if(array_search('next_column',$bottom_menu[$i]->classes)!==false) break;>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: As documentation states [array-search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) the second argument need to be array. Try var_dump on $bottom_menu[$i] - I guess it does not have `classes` attribute

Comment: @DavidWinder no it must return undefined property if not exists. i think it is null instead.

Answer (score 1):

check if $bottom_menu[$i]->classes empty also

```
<?php $i++;?>
** <?php if(!empty($bottom_menu[$i]->classes)) { ?> **
<?php if(array_search('next_column',$bottom_menu[$i]->classes)!==false) break;>
** <?php } ?> **
<?php endwhile;?>
```